# ng-bind-html inserts text instead of the actual element

Tags: angularjs

My HTML:

```
<div ng-if="vm.activePost.domain === 'gfycat.com'">
    <div ng-bind-html="vm.gfycatEmbed()"></div>
</div>
```

The Controller:

```
  gfycatEmbed(){
    return this.$sce.trustAsHtml(this.activePost.media.oembed.html);
  }
```

The string passed to trustAsHtml is this one:

[image]

And the output is this:

[image]

Can't for the life of me figure out what I'm missing.

I included 'ngSanitize' btw.

Comment: already tried that. no luck

Comment: where `this.activePost.media.oembed.html` comes from? I think your `<` is actually `$lt;` and so it doesn't think it's an html (?)

Comment: that was the problem. submit is as an answer